# Javascript blocking Submit Button from Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple HTML form with several buttons. With some assistance I have implemented a Javascript to handle different actions depending on which button is clicked, however I've just noticed that this also appears to suppress the value for the button that was clicked as a `POST` parameter.

I need to know the button that was clicked on the action page as it needs to branch conditionally as a result. Here's my HTML form:

```
<form role="form" action="index.php?action=updateItem" id="review" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="itemID" value="CBE21852-FF46-5F43-8A59-C59AAE865F28">

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="ticked" value="ticked" id="ticked" required></label>
    </div>
    <p>Quantities are correct<br>Size and orienation is correct<br>
    <hr>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="buttonType" id="Revision" value="PDF-proof">Revision</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="buttonType" id="Approved" value="Approved">Approved</button>
</form>
```

and here's my Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#review button[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();                                 // this for prevent form from submit

        if($(this).val() == "Approved"){                    // check if third button was clicked
            if($('#review #ticked').is(':checked')){        // check if checkbox is checked
                $('#review').submit();                      // submit form
            }else{
                alert("Please tick the checkbox before approving");
            }
        }else{                                              // any other button
            $('#review').submit();
        }
    });

    $("#rejectReason").validate({
        errorClass: "has-error"
    });
});
</script>
```

When I checked the form values on the index.php page all I see are the following:

```
Array
(
    [action] => updateItem
    [itemID] => CBE21852-FF46-5F43-8A59-C59AAE865F28
    [ticked] => ticked
)
```

Does anyone know how I can keep the functionality of the script but also include the button that was clicked as a POST parameter?

Comment: it is because the form submission is not done by the button click(that action is prevented by calling `preventDefaul()`), instead a programtic form submission which is unaware about the button that is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are preventing the form submission from the button click by calling `e.preventDefault();`. Then you are manually calling the form's submit method which is unaware about the button click.

A possible solution is to use `preventDefault()` on when you really want to prevent the form submission.

```
$('#review button[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).val() == "Approved") { // check if third button was clicked
        if (!$('#ticked').is(':checked')) { // check if checkbox is checked
            alert("Please tick the checkbox before approving");
            e.preventDefault(); // this for prevent form from submit
        }
    }
});
```

---

Since you are using the validator framework, I may change it to

```js
$(function() {
  $('#review button[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
    $('#buttonType').val(this.value)
  });
  $("#review").validate({
    rules: {
      ticked: {
        required: function() {
          return $('#buttonType').val() == 'Approved';
        }
      }
    },
    messages: {
      ticked: {
        required: 'Please tick the checkbox'
      }
    },
    errorClass: "has-error"
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form role="form" action="index.php?action=updateItem" id="review" method="post" novalidate>
  <input type="hidden" name="itemID" value="CBE21852-FF46-5F43-8A59-C59AAE865F28">

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="ticked" value="ticked" id="ticked" required>
    </label>
  </div>
  <p>Quantities are correct
    <br>Size and orienation is correct
    <br>
    <hr>

    <input name="buttonType" type="hidden" id="buttonType" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="buttonType" id="Revision" value="PDF-proof">Revision</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="buttonType" id="Approved" value="Approved">Approved</button>
</form>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c1q60m41/) -  <sub>The snippet won't work because of form submission if prevented in snippets</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could add another input hidden to hold which button is clicked. Simple Example:

```
<form role="form" action="" id="review" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="itemID" value="CBE21852-FF46-5F43-8A59-C59AAE865F28">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" /> <!-- container -->

    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="ticked" value="ticked" id="ticked" required></label></div>
    <p>Quantities are correct<br>Size and orienation is correct<br>
    <hr>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="buttonType" id="Revision" value="PDF-proof">Revision</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="buttonType" id="Approved" value="Approved">Approved</button>
</form>
```

Then in JS:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#review button[type="submit"]').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); // this for prevent form from submit
    $('input[name="action"]').attr('value', $(this).attr('id')); // assign the action made

    if($(this).val() == "Approved"){                 // check if third button was clicked
        if($('#review #ticked').is(':checked')){  // check if checkbox is checked
            $('#review').submit();                   // submit form
        } else {
            alert("Please tick the checkbox before approving");
        }
    }else{                                          // any other button
        $('#review').submit();
    }
    });

    $("#rejectReason").validate({
        errorClass: "has-error"
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make it an input type='submit' and change the name of the button

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="buttonType1" id="Revision" value="PDF-proof">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="buttonType2" id="Approved" value="Approved">
```